# How do I navigate from panel to panel in console mode of install4J installer?

Tags: install4j

well, all is in the title.
In InstallAnywhere when in console mode you type back or next or quit. I haven't seen something like this in install4j.

Thanks,

X.

Answer (score 0):

In install4j, console mode shows the user interface as a continuous stream of questions and so it's not organized into separate screens.

However, the installer has a "Console screen change handler" property where you can implement something like that. For example with code like

```
if (context.getBooleanVariable("showConsoleNavigation")) {
    if (console.askYesNo("Do you want to repeat the last step?")) {
        context.goBackInHistory(1);
    } else {
        console.println("* " + title);
    }
}
```

You would set the installer variable "showConsoleNavigation" to `Boolean.TRUE` once you want to start the navigation.